# Why i cannot change freestyle colour in eevee?

Tags: freestyle

happen only in eevee in 2.83 and 2.83.1.

Everytime i change the colour other than black it turn like this

[image]

works fine in cycle (freestyle in green)
[image]

already tried redownload blender and using factory settings

Comment: Strange, I tested on my machine (WIndows 10 - 2.83), and It works fine for me. Maybe some issue with your copy of blender, or maybe even graphics drivers?

Comment: im using Windows 10 / Intel UHD Graphics 630

Comment: Are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: Yes. I also tried the 2.9 version but still same. Maybe i just use 2.82 for now